# I cannot integrate Qt and VTK

Tags: qt, vtk

I am trying to integrate VTK and Qt but unfortunately for some reasons I cannot. Currently, I can run VTK's examples except those using Qt's user interface. For example, examples in tutorial work but examples in infovis cannot be run.

I followed the guide on http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Configure_and_Build. All parts were done successfully except :

```
cmake -DQT_QMAKE_EXECUTABLE:PATH=/path/to/qt-4.8.6-build/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.6/bin/qmake \
      -DVTK_Group_Qt:BOOL=ON \
      -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBRARIES:BOOL=ON \
      /path/to/VTK
```

when I was in VTK-build directory, it said that there was no `path/to/VTK`. So, I changed to VTK and removed `/path/to/VTK` and it worked.

Whenever I tried to build an aforementioned example, Qt says :

```
 cannot find -lQVTK
error: cannot find -lvtkRendering ....
```

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: Can you post your actual command (replacing "/path/to/VTK" with the actual path you passed it. Please also post what your directory structure looks like (is your 'build' inside or parallel to your 'source' tree?). I assume you have also replaced your /path/to/qt... with the actual path your Qt install?

Comment: Thanks for your response David. above code is exactly what I wrote. here is the structure: nima@Nima:~/projects$ ls VTK VTK-build. Then, from VTK, I entered the code without /path/to/VTK because the original form did not work when I wrote that from VTK-build

Comment: You mean VTK-build is a subdirectory of VTK? Then, from VTK-build, you need to do 
cmake -DQT_QMAKE_EXECUTABLE:PATH=/your/actual/path/to/qt-4.8.6-build/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.6/bin/qmake \
      -DVTK_Group_Qt:BOOL=ON \
      -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBRARIES:BOOL=ON \
      ../

(the ../ means "one directory up", and you need to know where your Qt is in order to set that path correctly)

Answer (score 1):

If you have installed the VTK in a folder named, say, "VTK-install", then check if you have **QVTK.lib** in the **VTK-install/lib/vtk-5.10/** folder. (your vtk version will be different though).

In the Qt Creator, you have to edit the pro file. This is what you have to add to the end of the pro file created in Qt creator.

```
INCLUDEPATH += C:\\VTK\\VTK-install\\include\\vtk-5.10

LIBS += -LC:\\VTK\\VTK-install\\lib\\vtk-5.10

LIBS += -lvtkCommon\
-lvtksys\
-lQVTK\
-lvtkViews\
-lvtkWidgets\
-lvtkInfovis\
-lvtkRendering\
-lvtkGraphics\
-lvtkImaging\
-lvtkIO\
-lvtkFiltering\
-lvtklibxml2\
-lvtkDICOMParser\
-lvtkpng\
-lvtkpng\
-lvtktiff\
-lvtkzlib\
-lvtkjpeg\
-lvtkalglib\
-lvtkexpat\
-lvtkverdict\
-lvtkmetaio\
-lvtkNetCDF\
-lvtksqlite\
-lvtkexoIIc\
-lvtkftgl\
-lvtkfreetype\
-lvtkHybrid\
```

And run it in release mode. This should work fine.

If this doesn't work, make sure you have installed Qt and VTK correctly. You can check out this tutorial on how you should install Qt with VTK in MS Visual Studio 2010.

[Install Qt with VTK](http://whimsandfancies1897.blogspot.tw/2014/06/how-to-set-up-qt-with-vtk-in-visual.html)

Of course, after this you got to install Qt creator which is better than Visual Studio to work with Qt.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I guess the problem is that I do not have vtk-6.0 in lib but in lib/cmake/vtk-6.0/modules. I also added LIBS += .. in my .pro file and I got "error: cannot find -lQVTK"

Comment: I am running Qt on Ubuntu, is there any guide for Ubuntu like [link](Install Qt with VTK) ?

Comment: Worked for me also with VTK 8